# gzip in jquery post

Tags: jquery, gzip

I'm doing a javascript post of a large chunk of data to a server, as base64 - and it is both slow and occasionally getting payload too large errors.  it's highly compressible data, and I'm wondering if I can force a gzip - can I just add a content-encoding:gzip header for instance - although how do I gzip the body.

My current code:

```
      $.ajax( {
          method: "POST",
          crossDomain: true,
          url:url,
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data : JSON.stringify(  { data_base64 : text } ),
          headers: { "x-api-key" : api_key, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
      })
```

what would I have to change to force this to always gzip the payload?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header as follows. Server should automatically compress the resources if compression is configured correctly at the server.

```
  $.ajax( {
      method: "POST",
      crossDomain: true,
      url:url,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data : JSON.stringify(  { data_base64 : text } ),
      headers: { "x-api-key" : api_key, "Content-Type": "application/json" , "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"}
  })
```

Comment: Should "Server should automatically compress ..." be "Browser should automatically compress ..."?  The question is about compressing data going up to the server, not compressing data coming down.